# Why devise display flash error message in error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Im using devise for my application, users need to sign up, so devise has some validations like uquiness of email and password length

this is the code to display the messages error

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

this is should be display the error validation to user, but this is how devise display it, just like error code !!

[the screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzGbV.png)

where is the problem ??

Comment: You are confusing the flash which is a session based way to pass messages between requests and model errors, which are the validation errors that are stored in the model (in memory) and are not persistent between requests.

Comment: `devise_error_messages!` displays model errors and does not have anything to do with the flash. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/715192a7709a4c02127afb067e66230061b82cf2/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
@user.save!
```

[save!](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) method throws an exception `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if validation fails. The exception causes the server to interrupt request processing and show the call stack.

To fix it you need to use [save](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) method instead, without an exclamation mark. For example:

```
if @user.save
  # user was saved successfully
else
  # validation failed, show devise error message
end
```